# localStorage undefined?

Tags: javascript, forms, local-storage

Im doing a website project in my first year in college and i need to get local storage working. All i need is to input information of my website form and then display the local storage in another form on antoher page. i had it working but i added extra inputs, i made sure my ids and names were correct but it still wont work. Heres a part of all 4 files. I need this as it is right now but for some reason it wont work. I cant use anything new.
!(http://i57.tinypic.com/9hkjfd.png)

```
<form action="readLocalStorage.html" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Sign Up</legend>
                <label for="username">Create a Username</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="5 characters" name="username" id="username" required><br><br>

<form name="LSdata" id="LSdata" action="addContact.php" method="post">

        <label>Username</label>
        <input name="username" id="username" readonly /><br />

function writeLocalStorage() {
localStorage.username = document.form1.username.value;
}
function getLocalStorage() {
document.LSdata.username.value = localStorage.username;
}
```

Comment: Tip: Read [**documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API).

Comment: You have two inputs with the same id

Comment: It wasnt supposed to be an input, fixed it and set to readonly. Fixed the veriables. Still unsuccessfull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your variables are mismatched.  You are setting `username` but getting `Username`.  In JavaScript, variables are case sensitive so `username` will not always equal `Username`, they are two different variables.

Using your functions:

```
function writeLocalStorage() {
  localStorage.username = 'mike';
}

function getLocalStorage() {
  console.log(localStorage.Username); // what you currently have, will return undefined
  console.log(localStorage.username); // returns "mike"
}

// returns:
//   undefined
//   mike
getLocalStorage();
```

Comment: It was working like I have it up there, copied exactly what the lecturer had. Thats whats confusing me.

Comment: Where do i exactly use the .setItem() method?

Comment: It's a method on `localStorage`.  Use it when you want to store something.

Comment: I believe index notation does the same thing, `localStorage['foo'] = 'bar'`

Comment: So it does, didn't know that!

Comment: @lukas13x Are there any errors that pop up in the console?  I did notice that you have `localStorage.username` as a setter and `localStorage.Username` as a getter.  In JavaScript, variables are case sensitive.

Comment: No, i made sure all my id's and names match. I had this working yesterday, then i decided to add email confirmation,username and passwords to my form. So i needed to edit the local storage as well. I add them 4 and it stopped. Now i get undefined in my readonly.  http://i57.tinypic.com/9hkjfd.png this is it

Comment: I've updated my answer to fix your issue.  Your variable names do not match.

Comment: Yeah i knew that javascript is case sensitive, this localStorage confused me but now i get what's going on. Still isn't working for me, changed it around. I still get undefined and doesnt appear in my chromes local storage.

Comment: So the problem was my validation, it was interfering for some reason. It worked fine, gave me errors if i tried to submit, say emails didnt match. but soon as i delted the validation if statements. all the localstorage worked. anyone know the reason behind this? thanks for your help as well mike.